# django haystack with elastic search - raise BulkIndexError

Tags: django, python-2.7, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am getting issue with " raise BulkIndexError while running this python manage.py rebuild_index ?

Here is my haystack configuration in settings.py file

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    #'SILENTLY_FAIL': False,
},
```

}

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'

Here is my search_indexes.py

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')

def get_model(self):
    return Product

def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

here is my views.py

```
def search_titles():

products = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.POST.get('search_text', ''))

return render_to_response('sea.html', {'products':products})
```

When I try to indexing the my product model I ran this command

> python manage.py rebuild_index

, It has not indexed. It raises

> File "/home/Documents/swamy/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/**init**.py", line 156, in streaming_bulk
>       raise BulkIndexError('%i document(s) failed to index.' % len(errors), errors)
>   elasticsearch.helpers.BulkIndexError: ('500 document(s) failed to index.'

this error.

My model has 21000 products, Can any one help to fix this issue ? 
Thanks In Advance !

Comment: Do you also have a stack trace in the Elasticsearch logs? If yes, please show it as well.

Comment: 'File ".../env_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 156, in streaming_bulk
    raise BulkIndexError('%i document(s) failed to index.' % len(errors), errors)
elasticsearch.helpers.BulkIndexError: ('500 document(s) failed to index.', ' , this is trace back of my error

Comment: Those are your python logs. What about the logs from your Elasticsearch server?

Comment: 'org.elasticsearch.indices.InvalidTypeNameException: mapping type name [_mapping] can't start with '_'
 at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:205)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:193)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.documentMapperWithAutoCreate(MapperService.java:412)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:325)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.'

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch changed the way bulk indices are created. 
You can use version 1.4.0 which works seamlessly with django-haystack.